# Dual Booting Delete Linux EFI partition

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

So I am trying to re-install the Linux on my laptop. Currently, I am dual booting between Windows and Linux and when I have checked I have two EFI System Partitions (ESP). I want to get rid of the one which I have created when installing Manjaro, and leave intact the Windows one, in case I want to revert back fully to Windows on that particular machine.

Is there a particular way to check which ESP is for Linux and which for Windows and Linux? I presume the first partition should be the Windows ESP, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run **`efibootmgr -v`** from Linux (which will show your EFI boot menu) and compare each entry's GUID with the GPT partition GUIDs that are shown by `partx /dev/sda` or `lsblk -o name,partuuid`.

You can also actually **look inside** and check what files are in each partition, as each ESP is just a standard mountable FAT32 partition:

- Windows always creates a `\EFI\Microsoft` directory and installs BOOTMGR (bootmgfw.efi) as its boot manager. You'll also find files like "BCD".
- Linux will generally install `grubx64.efi` or `systemd-bootx64.efi` as the boot manager. Generally, this will be the partition that Mint automatically mounts at /boot/efi.

---

In case you're only able to boot Windows but not Linux:

1. From an Administrator console, use `mountvol /s` to temporarily assign a drive to your current EFI system partition.
2. Then use `bcdedit /enum {bootmgr}` to verify that the EFI boot entry pointing to Windows BOOTMGR is indeed pointing to the same disk (it should show the letter that you just assigned):

   ```
   Windows Boot Manager
   --------------------
   identifier              {bootmgr}
   device                  partition=S:
   ```
3. Now the important partition is shown as S: in DiskMgmt, and the unimportant partition is still shown without a drive letter.

(You can also use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to list *all* EFI boot menu entries. This is the rough Windows equivalent of 'efibootmgr -v' from Linux.)