# how do I detect Grub partition in windows disk management

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

So, I had Ubuntu dual boot. I removed Ubuntu's Swap and root partition but I still think grub exists in my PC because on startup it comes up. Right now I'm booting directly to windows ssd via boot priority but still want to clean grub but I also don't want to remove my windows boot partition so I'm scared to remove any other EFI partition because I don't know which one is a grub and which one window boot

2 TB hard disk is not grub. Grub is on my 500GB SSD because that is what I used for Ubuntu. Help me remove grub
[image]

Comment: I think this post can help you out:
[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm scared to remove any other EFI partition because I don't know which one is a grub and which one window boot

Based on your screenshots, you only have one EFI partition in the first place.

Quite possible that either a) you already removed the Ubuntu one, or b) both Windows and Ubuntu are using *the same* EFI partition.

The EFI partition is just a regular FAT32 partition holding regular files, so uninstalling GRUB basically means deleting the files that were installed by GRUB (grubx64.efi, grub.cfg).

1. Use `mountvol S: /s` to assign a disk letter to the EFI partition.
2. Use commands such as `dir S:\`, `dir S:\EFI\`, etc. to look at what files are stored in that partition. Windows files will always be in \EFI\Microsoft, whereas Ubuntu might have installed GRUB into \EFI\Ubuntu or \EFI\Grub.
3. Delete the GRUB files.

However, deleting the files *will not remove* the EFI boot menu entry, nor the other way around. EFI boot entries are stored in the motherboard's NVRAM and managed using special tools, such as `efibootmgr` on Linux or `bcdedit` on Windows. (The latter is a confusing dual-purpose tool that simultaneously manages EFI entries and Windows BOOTMGR entries.)

1. Use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to list all EFI boot entries. The command will show their identifiers that you'll need to use later for deletion, as well as which partition and which file they point to.
2. If you see an entry named like "Ubuntu" or "GRUB", use `bcdedit /delete {the-identifier-here}` to remove it.

   Note: Many motherboards will also list virtual entries named "Firmware Application" or such. Do not try to delete those.

---

(If you actually had *two* EFI partitions, [this other thread](https://superuser.com/a/1600150/1686) is about figuring out which partition is used by what OS.)

Comment: No just one EFI partition. I cleaned one root and one 4gb swap. No other partition besides that. I think windows and Linux using this same EFI one

Comment: dir S:\EFI\ shows me `Microsoft`, `Boot`, `ubuntu`. How do delete `ubuntu`? `del S:\EFI\ubuntu`? That's it?

Comment: It's a directory, so to delete it fully (with its contents) you need `del -recurse` in Powershell or  `rd/s` in Cmd. (You can also use various third-party file manager apps -- the regular Windows Explorer won't work, but e.g. Total Commander or Far Manager should be able to access S: just fine.)